# DbDataReader error: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sqldatareader, dbdatareader

Hi I am trying to get return the DataReader from a method but it returns a closed DbDataReader object there. Any Idea to sort out this issue. I am open to any suggestions to make the code better.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I don't want to leave the Database connection Open. is there any way to return the open DataReader after closing the connection.

```
internal DbDataReader ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, string connectionString)
  {
    DbDataReader dataReader = null;
    try
    {
      SqlConnection connection = GetConnection(connectionString);
      Open(connection);
      command.Connection = connection;
      command.CommandTimeout = 60;
      dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(behavior);
      Close(connection);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return dataReader;
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `return dataReader;`, is it closed at this point?

Comment: hi @NeilKnight, yes its closed at that point

Comment: You might also want to think about your empty catch block.  You certainly wouldn't want to swallow all exceptions, would you?

Comment: Hi @BryanCrosby, its not empty. I am logging the errors. I just removed it while posting to make it short and readable. Thanks

Comment: Fair enough.  I would recommend leaving at least the type of exception you are trying to catch, e.g. catch (Exception exc) etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's closed because you closed the database connection. It can't read data from a closed SqlConnection. If you want to reuse the connection you may pass an OPEN connection to the method and the close the connection after you consumed data from the DbDataReader.

Comment: Hi @Adriano, will it be an issue if I leave the connection open?

Comment: You have to close the connection as soon as possible (server's connections are a finite resource) even if it'll be released by the garbage collector later. This does **not** mean you have to close the connection **immediately**, take the time to consume the data and then close the connection.